# Imageview in a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I 'm trying to display an image in a tablelayout. The image is shown once a picture is taken. When the image is displayed, it takes up the whole screen and a result my buttons disappear.
How can i fix this??
thanks

**XML file**

```
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:id="@+id/ImageViewRow">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:maxWidth="400dip"
                android:maxHeight="400dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious" android:text="@string/buttonPrevious"
                android:width="150px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonSave" android:text="@string/buttonSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:width="150px" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

****activity ****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the max width and height to a very large size.  If this is an application for a phone, then I would expect the behavior you describe.  Have you tried reducing the max size of the image within your table layout?

Comment: for some reason it didnt work earlier ..that was a stupid overlook on my part!